# How to add spell checker in soft keyboard?

Tags: android-layout, keyboard

I am creating custom keyboard using Latin IME. Is it possible to add spell checker bar in Latin-keyboard?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Do you have something that detects the use of the word "urgent" in a question? Seen you popping up a few times

Comment: Also I'm pretty certain this isn't anything to do with programming, correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @Matt: yep, [this bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=urgent%20is%3aquestion), I've got loads of them. I've been meaning to automate it with some sort of app, though I think there are several projects of that kind already (the [SO CVR room](https://socvr.org/) runs a couple of them). The boilerplate text [comes from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/master/sites/stackoverflow.com/questions.md).

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this

You will need to add this permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
```

**In java code**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {  
    UserDictionary.Words.addWord(this, "MadeUpWord", 10, "Mad", Locale.getDefault());
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
    UserDictionary.Words.addWord(this, "MadeUpWord", 10, UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE_TYPE_CURRENT);
}
```

for more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.Words.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me how to add suggestion bar in keyboard to display the suggestion .?